# How to save an image after resizing it in google colab?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

```
image = cv2.imread("/content/obj_measurement.jpg")

scale_percent = 12.5 # percent of original size
width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)

resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Now I want to download this resized image. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call the [`cv2.imwrite()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce) method:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("/content/obj_measurement.jpg")
scale_percent = 12.5
width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)

dim = (width, height)

resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imwrite("/content/obj_measurement_new.jpg", resized)
```

I would recommend unpacking the dimensions of the image rather than indexing though:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("/content/obj_measurement.jpg")
scale_percent = 12.5

h, w, _ = image.shape
dim = h * scale_percent / 100, w * scale_percent / 100

resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imwrite("/content/obj_measurement_new.jpg", resized)
```